What does dynamic="no" do
Can anyone tell me what dynamic="no" do in exp:channel:entries tags expression engine
T
thanks in advance

The channel:entries tag tries to determine what content to show based upon the url. So if the url is mysite.com/about/information-about-us EE will look at the url and determine that it probably needs to display an entry with the url_title "information-about-us"
However, when the url is mysite.com/about/information-about-us/more-information/ and you want to show the entry information-about-us it won't show you that, since it's now looking for an entry with a url_title of "more-information"
To prevent this you tell the channel:entries tag to show a specific entry and don't try to decide for itself
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment_2}" dynamic="no"}
